# Pullback of a constant sheaf over arbitrary sites

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, sites

Given a geometric morphism between arbitrary Grothendieck topoi, $f:\mathcal{Sh(D)}\to\mathcal{Sh(C)}$, does the pullback $f^{-1}$ (i.e, the left adjoint) take constant sheafs to constant sheafs?

Comment: Depends on how you define constant sheaves, for me by definition, constant sheaves are the sheaves of the form $p^*(S)$ where $p$ is the unique geometric morphism $Sh(D) \rightarrow Set = Sh(*)$. So yes.

Comment: Thanks! I was only looking at it as the sheafification of the constant presheaf, but your definition makes things more clear.

Comment: For more discussion on this see SGA IV exp IV section 4.3